# MySQL Sorting By 3 Columns

Tags: mysql, sql

**I get random "Results" every refresh** : I don't know why ...

```
SELECT  `area`,`subarea1`,`subarea2`
FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM users_activa_mutua_analitics
    ORDER BY `area`  ASC 
    LIMIT 100
) AS sub
ORDER BY `subarea1`  IS NOT NULL ASC, `subarea2`  IS NOT NULL ASC
LIMIT 5
```

I need order this form :

```
(area) (subarea1) (subarea2)
1           1          1
            1          1
            1          1
                       1
2           2          2
            2          2
            2          2
                       2
""          ""         ""
```

Comment: please add you table definitions and some sample data. it will be best if you create sqlfiddle for us. Thanks

Comment: You can create 3 fields "área" , "subarea"  and "subarea2"  you try use my ( query and values from table posted ) and refresh page (update query) and will see random position from this values

Comment: just a quick question for clarification: Does that table contains values which are not changing? to be more specific, I can see the name is `active users analitics`, is it updated periodically and when you select top 100 is it possible that you are getting a different top 100? Or is my assumption wrong?

Comment: The table contains "text" never change only change clicks, but only I need order category by subareas(neverchange) with numbers 1 (general) 11(utilities) 111(soundmeter) , 2(what to do) (not have 22 ) 222(solutions)

Comment: please post sample data. I take as the sample table from your question being as the expected result. I lost 20 minutes on trying to fully understand the problem. PS: your code doesn't return random values. See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ab3f5/2   So please clarify the question

Comment: Can you try in yout phpMyAdmin ? and try click refresh query everytime you get a random position :)

Comment: i am using sqlFiddle. I also tested it on SQL server with some code alteration. Please try to formulate a question which is easy to grasp. Which has `sample data` , `sample code` and `desired output`. You have provided `desired output` and `sample code`, what about the data? You can't have the input and the output the same, then why would you need a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with "ID"

I created a table with references about area subarea :

```
Id      Area         SubArea1       SubArea2
(1)    1(area)      0(subarea1)      1(subarea2)
(2)    1(area)      1(subarea1)      0(subarea2)
```

And I order "ID" ASC/DESC

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is enough data in your question but reading between the lines I have created an SQLFiddle of what I think you want: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/62f94) if this is correct then you do not need the sub query just

```
    SELECT area, subarea1, subarea2
    FROM users_activa_mutua_analitics
    ORDER BY subarea2 ASC,
        subarea1 IS NULL ASC,
        area IS NULL ASC
```

Comment: See my table posted, I think that I need subquery into subquery but I don't know how.